# xss - binding events

Tags: javascript, security, xss

With  Button1 in my website, I am able to add an event to it through the dev tools console (el = document.getElementById("Button1"); el.addEventListener("click", someFunction);). Is there a way to make my website more secure so that events can not be added once the website is published. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

After arriving in the browser, the page is under the control of the browser.

The browser works for the user, not for the page author.

Answer (score 1):

Imho there is no way to disable the dev tools.

You should consider that the DOM could have been manipulated and add security for this. Especially your back-end should not trust incoming requests blindly. Not for XSS only.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you still feel worried about this, you need to remember that once a user opens your website, he only has a local copy. He can do anything he wants to, like adding buttons, adding scripts, he could even transform it into an illegal website and it'll still no matter, because it's just a local copy, so he's the only one with those changes, and as soon as he refreshes the website, all those changes will disappear.

If you want an example, you can even modify the NASA's website with the dev tools, and that doesn't mean that it isn't secure.

And of course, you need to write code taking all this into consideration, because that means that you cannot trust user input at all. If you have a validation in your javascript, you also need to validate it in your backend, because as you could see, anyone could just override that validation.

**Edit:** Just to clarify something. XSS is when you inject code that will affect other users. For example, injecting javascript via the URL, and any user using that URL will execute that javascript, or javascript injected via a comments form and now every user reading that comment, will execute that javascript. But if you're the only one who has access to that script, just like happens with the dev tools, then it's not an XSS vulnerability, it's just the web browser working as it's intended to work.